# Lambda Calculus let explanation needed

Tags: haskell, let, lambda-calculus

In [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let_expression) treatment of `let` a lambda calculus version of `let` is given

```
(\f.z)(\x.y)
```

with the words

`f` is defined by `f x = y` *in the expression* `z`, and then as

```
let f x = y in z
```

I know from a beginner's perspective how Haskell's `let` works, i.e., the definitions follows the `let` and expressions (do something with those definitions) follows the `in`.

```
let <definitions> in <expression>
```

But this most general lambda calculus description is baffling. For example, I assume there could be a Haskell lambda function version of `let f x = y in z`. Could someone write this out -- and maybe give an example or two -- in Haskell? Just guessing, it seems a first lambda function takes a second lambda function -- somehow?

```
(\x -> y)(\f -> z)
```

But this is just a guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Haskell version is exactly the same as the lambda calculus version but with Haskell syntax:

```
(\f -> z) (\x -> y)
```

Why?

```
let f x = y in z
    ^^^^^^^ "local" function called "f"

let f = (\x -> y) in z
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ same thing without the function syntax
```

We are just introducing a new variable `f` which holds the value `(\x -> y)`.

How do we introduce a variable in lambda calculus? We define a function and then call it, like this:

```
(\x.zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz) 1
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ inside this part, x is 1
```

(lambda calculus doesn't have numbers, but you get the idea)

So we're just introducing a variable called `f` whose value is `(\x.y)`

Comment: So with `f = (\x -> y) in z` we might have `z` be `f 1`. Beta reduction (in Haskell) of `(\f -> z) (\x -> y)` would be `(\x -> y) z` ?

Comment: @147pm No. Beta reduction of `(\f -> z) 1` is `z` but with all free `f`s replaced with `1`s. And beta reduction of `(\f -> z) (\x -> y)` is `z` but with all free `f`s replaced with `(\x -> y)`. So if `z` doesn't have an `f` in it then it's just `z`. If `z` stands for something like `f 42 "hello"` then it's `(\x -> y) 42 "hello"`

Comment: Then we can have `(\f -> f 3)(\x -> x^2)` ==> `9` and `(\f -> f)(\x -> x^2) (3)` ==> `9`

Comment: Note that in Haskell that equivalence between `let` and its lambda encoding only works when `f` is monomorphic. Indeed, `let f = ..` can give a polymorphic type to `f`, while `(\f -> ...)...` does not. This is due to how type inference works, and this distinction I think was first introduced by the Hindley-Milner type system.

Comment: @147pm Beta reduction of `(\f -> f 3)(\x -> x^2)` is `(\x -> x^2) 3`, it is not `9`, you have to reduce more times to get `9`. Beta reduction *twice* gives you `3^2` and then evaluating that gives 9